# dynamically add elements from jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

if a user types in an input say 3 into a text box three small text boxes should be shown below or in a popup through javascript or jquery .How can this be done...

```
 <input type="text" name="order">3</input>
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind you should probably mask the textbox to allow only numerical entries...Or maybe use a drop down list with a list of numbers to prevent error. But [here](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) is a great jquery mask plugin to prevent non-numerical entries.

```
<input type="text" name="Order" onKeyDown="checkVal(this)">3</input>

<div id="myDiv">
</div>


function checkVal(ctrl){
   var val = ctrl.value;
   $('myDiv').html(''); // remove existing elements
   for (i=0;i<parseInt(val,10);i++){
      $('#myDiv').append('<input type="text" />');
   }
}
```

Comment: Always specify the radix as the second parameter to parseInt. This ensures that input like 0xAF and similar input isn't parsed in an undesired radix

Comment: That is going to put 4 textboxes in the div, not 3.  You need to change that to i<parseInt.

Comment: i<=parseInt(val)  should be   i<parseInt(val) ;)

Comment: Gah! What's with the obtrusive event handling?

Comment: @J-P its a simple example. I showed the logic of how to add the textboxes simply. The question didn't ask about anything regarding event handling. I'm betting he will use a submit button or something. Thanks for the down vote, unwarranted.

Comment: The onKeyDown handler will lead to the following behavior: User enters "3" -> 3 boxes are generated. User corrects himself, deletes 3 -> nothing happens. User types "4" -> four additional boxes are added (so you have 7). So you should either check for the number of existing boxes in #myDiv and add/remove boxes as needed. Or you use $('#myDiv').empty().append('<input type="textbox" />'); But with this the user will lose all text that was entered before in the boxes.

Comment: @gmcalab, if you know of the right way then why did you show him the wrong way? It's important to demonstrate good practices, even when they're not directly related to the core question. There are other issues with your code, which I won't dare go into now. My vote was not unwarranted -- I don't see this as a good answer.

Comment: A small suggestion, rather than looking up the #myDiv each time it would be better to store it as var container = $('#myDiv'); once and reference the container for each append operation.

Comment: @J-P - Good point. And yes, I like your solution better. I give you +1 :)

Answer (score 8):

Give the `<input/>` an id of "order", then it's as simple as:

```
var order = $('#order'),
    container = $('<div/>').insertAfter(order);

order.keyup(function(){
    container.html(
        Array(Math.abs(~~this.value) + 1).join('<input/>')
    );
});
```

FYI, `~~` (double-bitwise-not) has the effect of getting the number representation of any type (using the internal `toInt32` operation) and then flooring it. E.g:

```
~~'2'; // => 2
~~'2.333'; // => 2
~~null; // => 0
```

And `Math.abs` is to protect against negative values, that will throw an error if passed to `Array()`.

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/azexa4

Comment: Might be helpful for most readers if you explain the double bitwise NOT flooring. :)